# Runtime Error Using Scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in;
        in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String name;
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print(name);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me, how are you running this?

Comment: This code might not run from IDE but is ok for command line